# Parsing JSON response in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl

My code is:

```
self.ip = self.bot.get('https://icanhazip.com').content.rstrip().decode()
```

I want to replace `https://icanhazip.com` with `https://ipinfo.io`, but I don't know how to extract the `ip` returned:

```
$ curl "ipinfo.io"
{
  "ip": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
  "city": "",
  "region": "",
  "country": "xx",
  "loc": "xx.xxx.xx.xxx",
  "org": "xxxxxxx Communication Company (Private Joint Stock)"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear which HTTP library you're using in `self.bot.get`, but for a generic one (where `content` returns a string), you can parse the JSON response manually with [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json
# ...
ip = json.loads(self.bot.get('https://ipinfo.io').content).get('ip')
```

If you're using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), you can read the JSON response directly with [`json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) method on the response:

```
ip = self.bot.get('https://ipinfo.io').json().get('ip')
```

Comment: Thanks how can i sure which HTTP library im using in 'self.bot.get'

Comment: Take a look at `self.bot` definition, probably in your class `__init__` method.